# Using the esp register

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm, stack-pointer

I was trying to understand how to use the stack with assembly and in my attempt I came across the following code in one of the questions in SO, namely:

```
push    ecx

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, result
mov edx, result_len
int 0x80

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, esp
add [ecx], DWORD 48
mov edx, 2
int 0x80
```

In this case ecx, is holding a number and the author is displaying the number by (correct me if I am wrong!) first moving the stack pointer to ecx and then converting the number to ascii character by adding 48 to the memory address where ecx is pointing.
Would he have been able to do the same thing by "pop ecx" and then convert to ascii?
I do not quite understand why the author is proceeding in this way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would he have been able to do the same thing by "pop ecx" and then
>   convert to ascii?

No.  The sys_write system call, needs a pointer to the string to print.  By pushing `ecx` onto the stack, you create a pointer (address) in `esp`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however just to make sure I understand well, after 'mov ecx, esp' ecx is pointing to the memory location where the digit was stored and 'add [ecx], DWORD 48' will add 48 to that same memory location. Right?

Comment: Whatever was stored in `ecx` before the `push`, will be stored at the address of `esp` after the `push`

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain the code line by line

```
push    ecx #ADDS THE VALUE IN THE REGISTER ECX TO THE STACK (TO SAVE IT FOR LATER USE...)

mov eax, 4 #USE stdout AS OUR OUTPUT
mov ebx, 1 #USE stdout AS OUR OUTPUT
mov ecx, result #POINTER TO THE MEMORY ADDRESS OF THE CHARACTERS TO OUTPUT
mov edx, result_len #MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS TO SHOW
int 0x80 #EXECUTE THE INTERRUPTION 0X80

mov eax, 4 #USE stdout AS OUR OUTPUT
mov ebx, 1 #USE stdout AS OUR OUTPUT
mov ecx, esp #MOVE THE POINTER FROM THE STACK POINTER OT THE ECX REGISTER THAT LETS US ACCESS EXC IN THE STACK
add [ecx], DWORD 48 #ADDS TO THE VALUE INSIDE OF THE ECX REGISTER THE VALUE OF 48 AS A DWORD TO FIT THE EXTENDED SIZE 
mov edx, 2 #MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS TO SHOW
int 0x80
```

What I suppose this does is it gets a value of something and stores it in the stack, then it outputs a string to the stdout, afterwards it gets that value previously stored in the stacks and adds it 48 to all the register and finally outputs it.

This might also help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought bracketing the register as is the case in 'add [ecx], DWORD 48' (aka register indirect addressing), we are adding 48 to the address where ecx is pointing.

Comment: The square brackets indicate dereferencing of the address, much like * in C. The **value** from memory is about to be used as a pointer.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

Answer (score 0):

If we use EAX,EBX,ECX, or EDX as an addressregister inside of brackets, then DS is the default segment. But if we use ESP or EBP, then SS is the default segment.

So the instruction: "add [ecx], DWORD 48" add a dword value to the address where DS:ECX is pointing to.

But additional we can put a segment override prefix to our instruction for to override the default segment with an other one. Example: "add SS:[ecx], DWORD 48".